# Message splitting based on Terminator

Tags: java

I have a sample message file. I have to splite message from H to L|1|N as one message. Here two message into one file.  I want to put each message into an String [].
How can I do it?

I have tried such a way but not finished.

```
int beginIndex = eao.getBeginIndex();
int endIndex = MsgValidator.getTerminaterIndex(content) + 1;

logger.info("beginIndex:: "+beginIndex);
logger.info("endIndex:: "+endIndex);
if (endIndex > beginIndex) {
    String subContent = content.substring(beginIndex, endIndex-1);
    // need help
}
```

sample message::

```
H|\^&|||Becton Dickinson|||||||| V1.00 |19981019184200
P|1||PatId123
O|1|Acc123||^^^MGIT_960_AST
R|1|^^^AST_MGIT^439400001234^P^0.5^ug/ml|
INST_COMPLETE^105^^S||||||||19981019153400|19981020145000|
MGIT960^^42^3^ B/A13
L|1|N
H|\^&|||Becton Dickinson|||||||| V1.00 |19981019184200
P|1||PatId123
O|1|Acc123||^^^MGIT_960_AST
R|1|^^^AST_MGIT^439400001234^P^0.5^ug/ml|
INST_COMPLETE^105^^S||||||||19981019153400|19981020145000|
MGIT960^^42^3^ B/A13

L|1|N
```

Comment: Maybe just parse this txt file, with the old simple tools (inputstream->bufferedreader->filereader). Then parsing the txt by lines and if (first characters H| ->start the message) if the line is equal L|1N then the message is ended...

Or if you want to use the things(MsgValidator,eo) you mentioned, i think more of your code is needed...

Comment: I need to count how many complete message are in the file?Complete message means Starting from H and end L|1|N

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
if (endIndex > beginIndex) {
    String subContent = content.substring(beginIndex, endIndex - 1);
    String[] messages = subContent.split("L\\|1\\|N");
    logger.info("message :: " + messages.length);
}
```